# How to end my recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, maze

I need to program a method to solve a maze (2-dimensional array). I need to stay directly left of the wall at all times and my method should end when either I've reached the exit point (which is always at the same position) or when there is no solution possible (and, after running through the maze I'm back at the entry point).

I was able to do all that, no problems, I can visually ensure that it's doing what I want it to do (we've got some other methods from our instructor which output the visuals) and my console debug output is right as well.

This is the relevant code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    maze = generateMaze(10,10);
    walk(1,0,0);
}

public static void walk(int x, int y, int direction) {
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y); //debug output
    draw(x,y,maze); //draws current position
    if (x == maze.length-1 && y == maze[1].length-2) { //terminate when reached exit
        System.out.println("Geschafft!");
        return;
    }
    if (x == 1 && y == 0 && direction == 3) { //terminate when at starting point again (no solution)
        System.out.println("Keine Lösung möglich.");
        return;
    }
    if (direction == 0) { //go down
        if (maze [x][y+1]) {
            walk(x,y,1);
        }
        walk(x,y+1,2);
    }
    if (direction == 1) { //go right
        if(maze [x+1][y]) {
            walk(x,y,3);
        }
        walk(x+1,y,0);
    }
    if (direction == 2) { //go left
        if(maze [x-1][y]) {
            walk(x,y,0);
        }
        walk(x-1,y,3);
    }
    if (direction == 3) { //go up
        if(maze[x][y-1]) {
            walk(x,y,2);
        }
        walk(x,y-1,1);
    }    
}
```

There's just one problem: how do I end my recursion correctly? This is what I get form the console:

```
x = 1 y = 0
x = 1 y = 1
x = 1 y = 1
x = 1 y = 2
and so on...
x = 8 y = 8
x = 9 y = 8
Geschafft!
x = 8 y = 9
x = 8 y = 9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at maze.MazeSolution.walk(MazeSolution.java:26)
at maze.MazeSolution.walk(MazeSolution.java:39)
and some more of that
```

I do understand the error, the recursion obviously doesn't end where I want it to and x or y are increased and try to use an index in the array that isn't there.

Why doesn't the recursion end with the return statement, when either of these situations come true:

```
if (x == maze.length-1 && y == maze[1].length-2) { //terminate when reached exit
    System.out.println("Geschafft!");
    return;
}
if (x == 1 && y == 0 && direction == 3) { //terminate when at starting point again (no solution)
    System.out.println("Keine Lösung möglich.");
    return;
}
```

What do I need to do to end it correctly?

I greatly appreciate your help, show some love for a beginner and tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your returns and where you may return to.  You can return in the middle of your enclosing function which has other calls to walk, without the guards to ensure they're not called.

I recommend re-implementing your logic; think about having if/else pairs to ensure mutual exclusion.

Comment: So atm it's simply returning to the if (direction == x) statements?
While not being particularly elegant: if I wrap all statements into if/else statements like the first to, they can not be called when I've reached the exit/starting point, right?

Comment: It can return to those, and it can also return right above an unguarded call to another walk, as in the maze examples.  Each return brings you right below the invoking walk, which gives you several return poitns.  It's critical to trace the execution with the values that would hold on termination of the enclosing call.

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around that... I understand that, if my program reaches on of my end cases and hits return, it will end the recursion and return right back to the point where the recursion started. Am I right?
But how do I keep it from jumping to the next statement and executing it?

Comment: I got it now, it's enough to write clean if/else statements, e.g.:

   `if (direction == 0) { //go down
            if (maze [x][y+1]) {
                 walk(x,y,1);
            }
            else walk(x,y+1,2);
        } `
When the recursion returns the else-part will not be executed, effectively stopping right where I want it to. 

It's always the little things that are hard to figure out...

Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure.  Recursion confuses a lot of people; in principle, it's simple and elegant, but in practice, it can be very headache-inducing, especially when figuring out termination cases.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the beginning

```
public static void walk(int x, int y, int direction) {
  System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y); //debug output
  if (x >= 10 ||  x < 0 || y >= 10 || y < 0) return;
```

Comment: That's not working. It's basically doing the same as my end cases, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply return true or false and react on it?

So basically you add to your two end cases `return true;` for code ended.

```
if(walk(...)) return true;
```

Comment: I'd need to change the method's return type for that, which I'm not allowed to do. :(

Comment: Dann schreib doch mal die Aufgabenstellung dazu.

Comment: http://www2.in.tum.de/lehre/vorlesungen/WS07/info1/blatt04.pdf
Aufgabenstellung, allerdings nur in Deutsch. Das Blatt ist zwar von WS07, aber genau das gleiche.

Comment: Back in english: I don't see any restrictions about the prototype so you can change the return type and the arguments. Or I did I missed something?

Comment: It's a general directive form our instructors. Use the prototypes exactly as given.